# What language is spoken in Twin Peaks season 1, pilot episode and why?

Tags: plot-explanation, twin-peaks

In ***Twin Peaks***, season 1, pilot episode. Leland Palmer is called away from a presentation to a phone call from his wife when they learn their daughter is dead.

Shortly before he is called away, a group of old people are given a presentation, the main speaker speaks English and a translator translates it to a German-ish language.

Twin Peaks, a fictional town, is located in the state of Washington, which is on the border with Canada. I am wondering what language they speak and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The language is Norwegian. There's [a group of Norwegian investors](https://twinpeaks.fandom.com/wiki/Norwegians) visiting the Great Northern; Leland Palmer and Ben Horne are trying to get them to invest in a development project in Twin Peaks, but the scandal of Laura's murder drives them off.